# 'slideDown' was used before it was defined' Jquery, Brackets text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've started learning jQuery through Code Academy and I'm trying to implement some of what i've learned on my own site thought I'm getting errors in Brackets text editor.

In index html, I've linked to my Javascript file.

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'src='script.js'></script>
```

Then in my script.js, I've written.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

$('#logo').ready(slideDown(slow));
```

The errors I get are labeled as JSLint Problems

```
5   'slideDown' was used before it was defined.    
5 'slow' was used before it was defined.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: The `.slideDown()` method has to be used with a jQuery object. The word "slow" has to be passed in string form (`"slow"`) to the method.

Comment: Since it's to short for an answer, here you go: `$(function(){$('#logo').slideDown('slow');});`

Comment: am I not telling it to slideDown the 'div' with id #logo ?

Comment: You have to include jquery to use it.

Comment: No, you're not telling to slide down the `<div>` with id "logo".  That would be the code in phillip100's comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery, then use `slideDown()` function.

*Code*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logo').slideDown('slow');
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need import jquery library. You can use google hosted library.
2.x version

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or 1.x version

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you need use document ready event. this way you ensure that the document is loaded before handling
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('#logo').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the jquery function with a callback argument. This callback is executed when the document is ready.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

```
$(function() {
    // Document is ready
    $('#logo').slideDown('slow');
});
```